# Makefile to build a cuda .so file (shared library)

Tags: c++, makefile, cuda, shared-libraries, .so

I used the following Makefile to generate my_kernel.so file. The kernel.cuh contains only a function declaration:

```
void call_kernel(float *flattened_arr, float *out_arr_2, const int x_size, const int y_size, const int kernal_width);
```

However, when calling "call_kernel" function from another program, an error of undefined function "call_kernel" occurred.

My question is: Are the lines generate .o files and .so file correct?

```
$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -shared $(LIBRARIES) -fpic -o $@

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Here is the whole Makefile:

```
CC=g++-8
DEBUG=no

ifeq ($(DEBUG),yes)
    CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g
    LDFLAGS=-Wall -g
else
    CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g
    LDFLAGS=-Wall -g
endif

NVCC=nvcc
NVCC_FLAGS=
NVCC_LIBS=

INCPATH=inc
SRCPATH=src
OBJPATH=obj
LIBPATH=lib

# CUDA directory:
CUDA_INC = /usr/include
CUDA_LIB = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

DIR=/home/lee/Downloads/my_project

IDIR=$(DIR)/inc
_DEPS = kernel.cuh
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

SDIR=$(DIR)/src
_SRC = kernel.cu
SRC = $(patsubst %,$(SDIR)/%,$(_SRC))

ODIR=$(DIR)/obj
_OBJ = kernel.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

OUT=$(DIR)/lib/libmy_kernel.so

INCLUDES=-I$(CUDA_INC) -I$(IDIR)
LIBRARIES=-L$(CUDA_LIB) -lcudart_static -L$(CUDA_LIB) -lcudadevrt

default: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -shared $(LIBRARIES) -fpic -o $@

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean cleanall

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o

cleanall: clean
    rm -f $(OUT)
```

Many Thanks

Comment: This is 99% likely to be a C++ versus C linkage problem.

Comment: The suggested solution does not solve my problem. I wrote everything in c++ not c.

Comment: Found fixes to the issue in the makefile: `NVCC_FLAGS=--compiler-options -fPIC` and also `$(OUT): $(OBJ)
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(OBJ) $(LIBRARIES) -o $@`

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution from another source to fix the issue in the Makefile and the .so file works corectly now. The following is the correct Makefile:

```
CC=g++-8
DEBUG=no

ifeq ($(DEBUG),yes)
    CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g
    LDFLAGS=-Wall -g
else
    CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g
    LDFLAGS=-Wall -g
endif

NVCC=nvcc
NVCC_FLAGS=--compiler-options -fPIC
NVCC_LIBS=

INCPATH=inc
SRCPATH=src
OBJPATH=obj
LIBPATH=lib

# CUDA directory:
CUDA_INC = /usr/include
CUDA_LIB = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

DIR=/home/lee/Downloads/add_number

IDIR=$(DIR)/inc
_DEPS = kernel.cuh
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

SDIR=$(DIR)/src
_SRC = kernel.cu
SRC = $(patsubst %,$(SDIR)/%,$(_SRC))

ODIR=$(DIR)/obj
_OBJ = kernel.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

OUT=$(DIR)/lib/libmy_kernel.so

INCLUDES=-I$(CUDA_INC) -I$(IDIR)
LIBRARIES=-L$(CUDA_LIB) -lcudart_static -L$(CUDA_LIB) -lcudadevrt

# This will achieve the same thing!
# $(OUT): $(OBJ)
#   $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(LIBRARIES) -o $@ $^


default: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(OBJ) $(LIBRARIES) -o $@

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean cleanall

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o

cleanall: clean
    rm -f $(OUT)
```